# RestAssured - Get values from nested object using Groovy gson path

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

How to use rest assured to get the list of all the zips from the below below structure?

```
{
    "persons":[
        {
            "name": "",
            "age":"",
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "city": "..",
                    "zip": ".."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected result is `List<String>` which contains zip codes only using groovy gson path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
...

List<List<String>> temp = JsonPath.from(res).getList("persons.addresses.zip");
List<String> zips = temp.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(zips);
//[..]
```

Comment: Thanks. I do know java and I could have done that. My question was how to use groovy gson path here (which is used by restassured internally). But I appreciate your time.

Comment: @RamPrakash It seems no way to get a `List<String>` only with GPath.

Comment: yes, i ended up using stream already.

Comment: To future readers, please take a look at the `Xiao` answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [flatten()](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#flatten()) method to get the zip code:

```
List<String> zips =JsonPath.from(res).getList("persons.addresses.flatten().zip")
```

Comment: This is a the perfect solution. Thanks.

Comment: @RamPrakash please set this answer as the accepted answer if you think it's better than other ones:)